# HTML for SVG diagram

Tags: html, css, svg

How do I write the html to create a sitemap using SVG like the image given?
[diagram svg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XCMI1.png)

This is what I have so far

```html
<svg width="400" height="200">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="100" height="100" style="fill:lightblue;stroke-width:2;stroke:black" onclick=""/>
            <text x="50" y="60" text-anchor="middle">MY PAGE</text>
            <line x1="50" y1="100" x2="50" y2="130" style="stroke:black;stroke-width:2;marker-end:url(#arrowhead)" />
            <line x1="50" y1="130" x2="25" y2="150" style="stroke:black;stroke-width:2;marker-end:url(#arrowhead)" />
            <line x1="50" y1="130" x2="75" y2="150" style="stroke:black;stroke-width:2;marker-end:url(#arrowhead)" />
            <rect x="0" y="100" width="100" height="100" style="fill:lightblue;stroke-width:2;stroke:black" onclick=""/>
            <text x="50" y="160" text-anchor="middle">ABOUT ME</text>
            <rect x="100" y="100" width="100" height="100" style="fill:lightblue;stroke-width:2;stroke:black" onclick=""/>
            <text x="150" y="160" text-anchor="middle">CONTACT ME</text>
            <rect x="200" y="100" width="100" height="100" style="fill:lightblue;stroke-width:2;stroke:black" onclick=""/>
            <text x="250" y="160" text-anchor="middle">MY PORTFOLIO</text>
            <defs>
              <marker id="arrowhead" markerWidth="10" markerHeight="7" refX="0" refY="3.5" orient="auto">
                <polygon points="0 0, 10 3.5, 0 7" />
              </marker>
            </defs>
          </svg>
```

Comment: you can probably modify [this](https://codepen.io/ross-angus/pen/jwxMjL) for your needs, or maybe use a flex-box and play around with it.

Answer (score 1):

Creating this from code alone would be challenging. If you have a vector program that enables export to .svg, the easiest way to do this is to create the illustration then export the HTML as an .svg file. You can use CSS to alter the color .svg to preference. Here is an example of what the syntax would look like.

```
    <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" width="1080px" height="504px" viewBox="0 0 1080 504" enable-background="new 0 0 1080 504" xml:space="preserve">
<g>
<g>
<polygon fill="#34495E" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.0034" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="477.945,31.667 477.945,179.667    609.945,179.667 609.945,49.286 592.945,32.17        "/>
<path fill="#34495E" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.0034" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M609.945,49.286l-16.5-16.612l4.5,17.116C597.945,49.79,599.945,44.252,609.945,49.286z"/>
</g>
<g>
<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M515.852,106.705c-0.108-2.041-0.239-4.516-0.239-6.318h-0.043c-0.521,1.693-1.107,3.539-1.846,5.559
        l-2.584,7.1h-1.433l-2.388-6.97c-0.695-2.084-1.26-3.952-1.672-5.689h-0.043c-0.043,1.824-0.152,4.256-0.282,6.471l-0.391,6.275
        h-1.802l1.021-14.635h2.41l2.497,7.079c0.608,1.802,1.086,3.409,1.477,4.929h0.043c0.391-1.477,0.912-3.083,1.563-4.929
        l2.605-7.079h2.41l0.912,14.635h-1.868L515.852,106.705z"/>

<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M524.233,113.132v-6.21l-4.646-8.425h2.172l2.062,4.039c0.543,1.107,0.999,1.998,1.454,3.018h0.044
        c0.391-0.955,0.912-1.911,1.477-3.018l2.106-4.039h2.128l-4.886,8.403v6.232H524.233z"/>

<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M537.328,98.671c0.911-0.152,2.105-0.282,3.626-0.282c1.867,0,3.235,0.434,4.104,1.216
        c0.781,0.695,1.281,1.759,1.281,3.062c0,1.325-0.391,2.367-1.129,3.127c-1.021,1.064-2.628,1.606-4.474,1.606
        c-0.564,0-1.085-0.021-1.52-0.13v5.863h-1.889V98.671z M539.217,105.728c0.412,0.108,0.934,0.152,1.563,0.152
        c2.279,0,3.669-1.129,3.669-3.105c0-1.954-1.39-2.888-3.452-2.888c-0.825,0-1.455,0.065-1.78,0.152V105.728z"/>

<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M549.423,108.529l-1.52,4.603h-1.954l4.994-14.635h2.258l4.994,14.635h-2.02l-1.563-4.603H549.423z
         M554.243,107.052l-1.455-4.212c-0.325-0.956-0.542-1.824-0.76-2.671h-0.043c-0.218,0.847-0.435,1.759-0.738,2.649l-1.434,4.234
        H554.243z"/>
```

```
<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M581.604,106.271h-5.667v5.276h6.341v1.585h-8.251V98.497h7.925v1.585h-6.015v4.625h5.667V106.271z"/>
</g>
</g>
<g>
<g>
<polygon fill="#34495E" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.0034" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="72.432,324.07 72.432,472.07 
        204.433,472.07 204.433,341.689 187.433,324.573      "/>
<path fill="#34495E" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.0034" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
        M204.433,341.689l-16.5-16.612l4.5,17.115C192.433,342.192,194.433,336.655,204.433,341.689z"/>
</g>
<g>

<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M92.175,400.932l-1.52,4.604h-1.954l4.994-14.635h2.258l4.994,14.635h-2.02l-1.563-4.604H92.175z
         M96.995,399.455l-1.455-4.212c-0.326-0.956-0.542-1.824-0.76-2.671h-0.043c-0.217,0.847-0.434,1.759-0.738,2.648l-1.433,4.234
        H96.995z"/>

<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M103.098,391.117c0.825-0.195,2.149-0.325,3.452-0.325c1.889,0,3.105,0.325,3.995,1.063
        c0.76,0.564,1.238,1.434,1.238,2.584c0,1.434-0.955,2.671-2.475,3.214v0.065c1.39,0.325,3.018,1.477,3.018,3.647
        c0,1.259-0.5,2.236-1.259,2.931c-0.999,0.934-2.649,1.369-5.038,1.369c-1.303,0-2.302-0.088-2.931-0.174V391.117z M104.986,397.11
        h1.715c1.976,0,3.148-1.063,3.148-2.476c0-1.693-1.281-2.389-3.191-2.389c-0.869,0-1.368,0.066-1.672,0.131V397.11z
         M104.986,404.102c0.391,0.065,0.912,0.088,1.585,0.088c1.954,0,3.756-0.717,3.756-2.845c0-1.976-1.715-2.823-3.778-2.823h-1.563
        V404.102z"/>

<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M127.374,398.066c0,5.016-3.062,7.707-6.796,7.707c-3.887,0-6.579-3.018-6.579-7.447
        c0-4.646,2.866-7.687,6.774-7.687C124.79,390.64,127.374,393.701,127.374,398.066z M115.996,398.283
        c0,3.148,1.694,5.949,4.69,5.949c2.997,0,4.69-2.758,4.69-6.08c0-2.932-1.52-5.971-4.668-5.971S115.996,395.092,115.996,398.283z"/>

<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M131.717,390.9v8.686c0,3.257,1.455,4.646,3.409,4.646c2.149,0,3.561-1.434,3.561-4.646V390.9h1.911v8.555
        c0,4.495-2.367,6.318-5.537,6.318c-2.997,0-5.255-1.693-5.255-6.253v-8.62H131.717z"/>

<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M146.657,392.508h-4.451V390.9h10.834v1.607h-4.473v13.027h-1.911V392.508z"/>

<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M171.607,399.107c-0.108-2.041-0.239-4.516-0.239-6.318h-0.043c-0.521,1.693-1.107,3.539-1.846,5.559
        l-2.584,7.101h-1.433l-2.389-6.97c-0.695-2.084-1.26-3.952-1.672-5.689h-0.044c-0.043,1.824-0.151,4.256-0.282,6.471l-0.391,6.275
        h-1.802l1.021-14.635h2.41l2.497,7.078c0.607,1.803,1.085,3.409,1.477,4.93h0.043c0.391-1.477,0.912-3.084,1.563-4.93l2.605-7.078
        h2.41l0.912,14.635h-1.867L171.607,399.107z"/>

<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M184.288,398.674h-5.667v5.276h6.341v1.585h-8.251V390.9h7.925v1.585h-6.015v4.625h5.667V398.674z"/>
</g>
</g>
<g>
<g>

<polygon fill="#34495E" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.0034" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="356.466,324.07 356.466,472.07 
        488.466,472.07 488.466,341.689 471.466,324.573      "/>

<path fill="#34495E" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.0034" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
        M488.466,341.689l-16.5-16.612l4.5,17.115C476.466,342.192,478.466,336.655,488.466,341.689z"/>
</g>
<g>

<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M389.096,405.079c-0.673,0.348-2.084,0.694-3.865,0.694c-4.126,0-7.209-2.605-7.209-7.426
        c0-4.604,3.105-7.686,7.643-7.686c1.802,0,2.975,0.391,3.474,0.65l-0.478,1.542c-0.695-0.347-1.715-0.608-2.932-0.608
        c-3.431,0-5.71,2.193-5.71,6.037c0,3.604,2.063,5.884,5.602,5.884c1.172,0,2.345-0.239,3.105-0.608L389.096,405.079z"/>

<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M403.536,398.066c0,5.016-3.062,7.707-6.796,7.707c-3.887,0-6.579-3.018-6.579-7.447
        c0-4.646,2.866-7.687,6.774-7.687C400.952,390.64,403.536,393.701,403.536,398.066z M392.158,398.283
        c0,3.148,1.694,5.949,4.69,5.949c2.997,0,4.69-2.758,4.69-6.08c0-2.932-1.52-5.971-4.668-5.971S392.158,395.092,392.158,398.283z"/>

<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M405.991,405.535V390.9h2.084l4.668,7.404c1.064,1.715,1.933,3.257,2.606,4.756l0.065-0.022
        c-0.174-1.954-0.217-3.735-0.217-6.015V390.9h1.781v14.635h-1.911l-4.647-7.426c-1.021-1.629-1.998-3.301-2.714-4.886
        l-0.065,0.022c0.109,1.846,0.13,3.604,0.13,6.035v6.254H405.991z"/>

<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M423.058,392.508h-4.451V390.9h10.834v1.607h-4.473v13.027h-1.911V392.508z"/>

<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M431.81,400.932l-1.52,4.604h-1.954l4.994-14.635h2.258l4.994,14.635h-2.02l-1.563-4.604H431.81z
         M436.629,399.455l-1.455-4.212c-0.326-0.956-0.542-1.824-0.76-2.671h-0.043c-0.217,0.847-0.434,1.759-0.738,2.648l-1.433,4.234
        H436.629z"/>

<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M452.612,405.079c-0.673,0.348-2.085,0.694-3.865,0.694c-4.125,0-7.209-2.605-7.209-7.426
        c0-4.604,3.105-7.686,7.644-7.686c1.802,0,2.975,0.391,3.474,0.65l-0.478,1.542c-0.694-0.347-1.715-0.608-2.931-0.608
        c-3.431,0-5.711,2.193-5.711,6.037c0,3.604,2.062,5.884,5.602,5.884c1.173,0,2.346-0.239,3.105-0.608L452.612,405.079z"/>

<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M458.388,392.508h-4.451V390.9h10.835v1.607h-4.474v13.027h-1.91V392.508z"/>

<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M420.908,425.166c-0.108-2.041-0.239-4.516-0.239-6.318h-0.043c-0.521,1.693-1.107,3.539-1.846,5.559
        l-2.584,7.1h-1.433l-2.388-6.969c-0.695-2.085-1.26-3.953-1.672-5.689h-0.043c-0.043,1.824-0.152,4.256-0.282,6.471l-0.391,6.275
        h-1.802l1.021-14.635h2.41l2.497,7.078c0.608,1.803,1.086,3.408,1.477,4.929h0.043c0.391-1.477,0.912-3.083,1.563-4.929
        l2.605-7.078h2.41l0.912,14.635h-1.868L420.908,425.166z"/>

<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M433.589,424.732h-5.667v5.275h6.34v1.586h-8.251v-14.635h7.925v1.584h-6.015v4.625h5.667V424.732z"/>
</g>
</g>
<g>
<g>

<polygon fill="#34495E" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.0034" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="628.734,324.07 628.734,472.07 
        760.735,472.07 760.735,341.689 743.735,324.573      "/>

<path fill="#34495E" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.0034" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
        M760.735,341.689l-16.5-16.612l4.5,17.115C748.735,342.192,750.735,336.655,760.735,341.689z"/>
</g>
<g>

<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M692.645,399.107c-0.108-2.041-0.238-4.516-0.238-6.318h-0.044c-0.521,1.693-1.107,3.539-1.846,5.559
        l-2.584,7.101H686.5l-2.389-6.97c-0.694-2.084-1.26-3.952-1.672-5.689h-0.043c-0.044,1.824-0.152,4.256-0.282,6.471l-0.392,6.275
        h-1.802l1.021-14.635h2.41l2.497,7.078c0.607,1.803,1.086,3.409,1.477,4.93h0.043c0.391-1.477,0.912-3.084,1.563-4.93l2.605-7.078
        h2.41l0.912,14.635h-1.867L692.645,399.107z"/>

<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M701.027,405.535v-6.21l-4.646-8.425h2.171l2.062,4.039c0.543,1.107,0.999,1.997,1.455,3.018h0.043
        c0.392-0.955,0.912-1.91,1.477-3.018l2.106-4.039h2.128l-4.886,8.402v6.232H701.027z"/>

<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M642.354,417.133c0.911-0.152,2.105-0.283,3.626-0.283c1.867,0,3.235,0.435,4.104,1.217
        c0.781,0.694,1.281,1.758,1.281,3.061c0,1.325-0.391,2.367-1.129,3.127c-1.021,1.064-2.628,1.607-4.474,1.607
        c-0.564,0-1.085-0.021-1.52-0.131v5.863h-1.889V417.133z M644.243,424.189c0.412,0.108,0.934,0.151,1.563,0.151
        c2.279,0,3.669-1.129,3.669-3.104c0-1.955-1.39-2.889-3.452-2.889c-0.825,0-1.455,0.065-1.78,0.152V424.189z"/>

<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M666.413,424.124c0,5.016-3.062,7.708-6.796,7.708c-3.887,0-6.579-3.018-6.579-7.447
        c0-4.646,2.866-7.688,6.774-7.688C663.829,416.697,666.413,419.76,666.413,424.124z M655.035,424.341
        c0,3.148,1.694,5.95,4.69,5.95s4.69-2.758,4.69-6.08c0-2.932-1.521-5.971-4.669-5.971S655.035,421.149,655.035,424.341z"/>

<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M668.868,417.154c0.955-0.174,2.345-0.305,3.626-0.305c2.02,0,3.344,0.391,4.234,1.194
        c0.717,0.651,1.15,1.65,1.15,2.802c0,1.91-1.216,3.191-2.735,3.713v0.064c1.107,0.391,1.78,1.434,2.128,2.953
        c0.478,2.041,0.825,3.453,1.129,4.018h-1.954c-0.239-0.435-0.564-1.672-0.955-3.496c-0.435-2.02-1.238-2.779-2.953-2.845h-1.781
        v6.341h-1.889V417.154z M670.757,423.82h1.933c2.02,0,3.301-1.107,3.301-2.779c0-1.89-1.368-2.715-3.365-2.715
        c-0.912,0-1.542,0.065-1.868,0.152V423.82z"/>

<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M683.525,418.565h-4.451v-1.606h10.834v1.606h-4.473v13.028h-1.91V418.565z"/>

<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M691.517,416.959h7.882v1.584h-5.972v4.864h5.516v1.563h-5.516v6.623h-1.91V416.959z"/>

<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M714.62,424.124c0,5.016-3.062,7.708-6.796,7.708c-3.887,0-6.579-3.018-6.579-7.447
        c0-4.646,2.866-7.688,6.774-7.688C712.036,416.697,714.62,419.76,714.62,424.124z M703.242,424.341c0,3.148,1.694,5.95,4.69,5.95
        s4.69-2.758,4.69-6.08c0-2.932-1.521-5.971-4.669-5.971S703.242,421.149,703.242,424.341z"/>

<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M717.054,416.959h1.91v13.049h6.254v1.586h-8.164V416.959z"/>

<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M729.213,416.959v14.635h-1.91v-14.635H729.213z"/>

<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M745.021,424.124c0,5.016-3.062,7.708-6.797,7.708c-3.887,0-6.579-3.018-6.579-7.447
        c0-4.646,2.866-7.688,6.775-7.688C742.438,416.697,745.021,419.76,745.021,424.124z M733.644,424.341
        c0,3.148,1.693,5.95,4.69,5.95c2.996,0,4.689-2.758,4.689-6.08c0-2.932-1.52-5.971-4.668-5.971S733.644,421.149,733.644,424.341z"/>
</g>
</g>
<g>
<g>

<polygon fill="#34495E" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.0034" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="875.793,324.07 875.793,472.07 
        1007.794,472.07 1007.794,341.689 990.794,324.573        "/>

<path fill="#34495E" stroke="#FFFFFF" stroke-width="1.0034" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="
        M1007.794,341.689l-16.5-16.612l4.5,17.115C995.794,342.192,997.794,336.655,1007.794,341.689z"/>
</g>
<g>

<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M911.301,399.107c-0.108-2.041-0.239-4.516-0.239-6.318h-0.043c-0.521,1.693-1.107,3.539-1.846,5.559
        l-2.584,7.101h-1.434l-2.388-6.97c-0.695-2.084-1.26-3.952-1.672-5.689h-0.044c-0.043,1.824-0.152,4.256-0.282,6.471l-0.391,6.275
        h-1.803l1.021-14.635h2.41l2.497,7.078c0.608,1.803,1.086,3.409,1.477,4.93h0.044c0.391-1.477,0.912-3.084,1.563-4.93l2.605-7.078
        h2.41l0.912,14.635h-1.868L911.301,399.107z"/>

<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M919.683,405.535v-6.21l-4.646-8.425h2.172l2.062,4.039c0.543,1.107,0.999,1.997,1.454,3.018h0.044
        c0.391-0.955,0.912-1.91,1.477-3.018l2.106-4.039h2.128l-4.886,8.402v6.232H919.683z"/>

<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M932.755,390.9h1.911v13.05h6.253v1.585h-8.164V390.9z"/>

<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M944.915,390.9v14.635h-1.911V390.9H944.915z"/>

<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M948.216,405.535V390.9h2.085l4.668,7.404c1.064,1.715,1.933,3.257,2.605,4.756l0.065-0.022
        c-0.174-1.954-0.217-3.735-0.217-6.015V390.9h1.78v14.635h-1.911l-4.646-7.426c-1.021-1.629-1.998-3.301-2.714-4.886l-0.065,0.022
        c0.108,1.846,0.13,3.604,0.13,6.035v6.254H948.216z"/>

<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M962.505,390.9h1.889v7.057h0.065c0.391-0.564,0.781-1.086,1.15-1.562l4.474-5.494h2.345l-5.298,6.21
        l5.71,8.425h-2.236l-4.799-7.188l-1.411,1.607v5.58h-1.889V390.9z"/>

<path fill="#FFFFFF" d="M974.035,403.233c0.847,0.543,2.062,0.956,3.366,0.956c1.932,0,3.062-1.021,3.062-2.498
        c0-1.346-0.782-2.148-2.758-2.887c-2.389-0.869-3.865-2.129-3.865-4.17c0-2.279,1.89-3.973,4.733-3.973
        c1.477,0,2.584,0.347,3.214,0.716l-0.521,1.542c-0.456-0.282-1.433-0.695-2.757-0.695c-1.998,0-2.758,1.194-2.758,2.193
        c0,1.368,0.89,2.041,2.909,2.822c2.476,0.956,3.713,2.15,3.713,4.3c0,2.258-1.65,4.233-5.103,4.233
        c-1.411,0-2.953-0.434-3.734-0.955L974.035,403.233z"/>
</g>
</g>

<line fill="none" stroke="#34495E" stroke-width="1.0034" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="139.202" y1="251.453" x2="941.723" y2="251.453"/>
<g>

<line fill="none" stroke="#34495E" stroke-width="1.0034" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="420.5" y1="251.75" x2="420.5" y2="323"/>

<polyline fill="none" stroke="#34495E" stroke-width="1.0034" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="408.75,310.5 420.25,321.498 
    432.25,310.75   "/>
</g>
<g>

<line fill="none" stroke="#34495E" stroke-width="1.0034" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="139" y1="251.75" x2="139" y2="323"/>

<polyline fill="none" stroke="#34495E" stroke-width="1.0034" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="127.25,310.5 138.75,321.498 
    150.75,310.75   "/>
</g>
<g>

<line fill="none" stroke="#34495E" stroke-width="1.0034" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="694" y1="251.75" x2="694" y2="323"/>

<polyline fill="none" stroke="#34495E" stroke-width="1.0034" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="682.25,310.5 693.75,321.498 
    705.75,310.75   "/>
</g>
<g>

<line fill="none" stroke="#34495E" stroke-width="1.0034" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="943" y1="251.75" x2="943" y2="323"/>

<polyline fill="none" stroke="#34495E" stroke-width="1.0034" stroke-miterlimit="10" points="931.25,310.5 942.75,321.498 954.75,310.75   "/>
</g>

<line fill="none" stroke="#34495E" stroke-width="1.0034" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="539.18" y1="178.865" x2="539.18" y2="251.116"/>
</svg>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jasonbruce/twp94jbq/

Answer (score 1):

Instead of laying out the entire thing in SVG you could combine HTML with SVG as background images. So, elements can be styled with a before and after pseudo element what has an SVG as background.

If there should be more levels this probably needs to be refactured a bit.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.page {
  width: 100px;
}

.page div {
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 5px;
  background-color: lightblue;
  border: thin solid black;
}

.middle:before {
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  content: "";
}

.left:before {
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  content: "";
}

.right:before {
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,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');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  content: "";
}

.parent:after {
  display: block;
  height: 40px;
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTAwIDQwIiB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5vcmcvMjAwMC9zdmciPgo8cGF0aCBkPSJNIDUwIDAgViA0MCIgc3Ryb2tlPSJibGFjayIgc3Ryb2tlLXdpZHRoPSIyIi8+Cjwvc3ZnPg==');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  content: "";
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="page parent">
    <div>MY PAGE</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div class="page left">
    <div>ABOUT ME</div>
  </div>
  <div class="page middle">
    <div>CONTACT ME</div>
  </div>
  <div class="page middle">
    <div>CONTACT ME 2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="page right">
    <div>MY PORTFOLIO</div>
  </div>
</div>
```